# Bulk uploading places into Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I was wondering what is the best approach when you would like to bulk upload data for a few hundred restaurants / businesses  to Google Maps to be able to query it via Google Places API and for it to be visible via Google Maps Local.

I saw Places Actions in the Places API:
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/actions
but it does not seem to allow me to take ownership of a place.

Plus the syntax is:

```
POST maps/api/place/add/json?sensor=true_or_false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
Host: maps.googleapis.com

{
 "location": {
  "lat": -33.8669710,
  "lng": 151.1958750
},
"accuracy": 50,
"name": "Google Shoes!",
"types": ["shoe_store"],
"language": "en-AU"
}
```

so I can't really see how can I add description and opening times.

I want to be able to see all the Places I uploaded, but I also want to give the local managers the option to add data for a place and change things like opening hours (since we not always have up do date information)

Answer (score 2):

Yes - the Places Actions API only allows you to perform a limited set of actions.

Consider using [Places for Business](https://www.google.com/business/) to manage your restaurants.

If you have a lot of places to update, you can follow the instructions in the Help Centre article "[Add 10 or more listings](http://support.google.com/places/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178024#3)" to update or create them by uploading a spreadsheet.